# Possible to avoid repetition of expression in a QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to display time in a weird format.
For example, if time is 15:30:45.5000, I need to display "153045.5".

To do this, I have the following query:

```
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 114), 2) +     
   SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 114), 4, 2) +   
   SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 114), 7, 2) + '.' + 
   SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 114), 10, 1);
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid repeating the expression CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 114)?

Edit:

I saw a really cool answer here which was deleted for some reason after I refreshed the page, but it gave me the idea to think of an alternative solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(21), getdate(), 126), 10), ':', '')
```

Although this answer doesn't solve the original question in a generic way, it still solves my problem in a different way.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: If at all possible; consider formatting the output in the presentation layer.

Comment: BTW: The format I am getting when running your code does not match the format you say you are trying to get.

Comment: I hope the . is a typo.  "45.5"   Please review the question.

Comment: You're right. I actually want a '.' to separate the seconds from the milliseconds. I will fix the query.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to functions in other answers, you can calculate a partial result in a common table expression (CTE) or inline view:

```
; WITH gd(getDate_114)
     AS (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 114))
SELECT LEFT(getDate_114, 2)
    + SUBSTRING(gd.getDate_114, 4, 2) 
    + SUBSTRING(gd.getDate_114, 7, 2)
    + '.'
    + SUBSTRING(gd.getDate_114, 10, 1)
FROM gd
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap all the formatting code in a function

```
create function dbo.FormatTime (@time datetime) 
returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    return (select LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(20), @time, 114), 2) 
            + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), @time, 114), 4, 2) 
            + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), @time, 114), 7, 4))
end
```

And use it as

```
select dbo.FormatTime(getdate())
```

To avoid repetition in the function body, you can store the `@time` converted to `varchar` in a variable

```
declare @dateAsVarchar varchar(20) = CONVERT(varchar(20), @time, 114)

return (select LEFT(@dateAsVarchar, 2) 
        + SUBSTRING(@dateAsVarchar, 4, 2) 
        + SUBSTRING(@dateAsVarchar, 7, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unless I'm mistaken, there isn't a way to minimize this in SQL Server 2008 R2.  You'll have to construct it the way you're already doing it.  Another option (as already pointed out by @jonasnas) would be to create a function that returns the format of the current date.

If you are able/willing to upgrade to SQL Server 2012, however, you can take advantage of the `FORMAT()` function to format the string:

```
Select Format(GetDate(), N'HHmmss.f')
```

Comment: The : is a . or nothing.   The existing query from the OP  is different than the stated desired output.  Still +1